# Android how to make clickable logo icon in actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I`m using SherlockActionBar for my application. In my manifest I define icon for logo and launch.

```
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

How to make it clickable and handle the event of it`s pressing? I want to be able to back to my dashboard by pressing the logo.

Comment: in onCreate of activity `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` then `@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case android.R.id.home:
   /* icon clicked */
   return true;}return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);}`

Comment: Thanks @Selvin, I did not have the `Support` part of `getSupportActionBar()` and Android Studio was telling me it might be null. Adding `Support` fixed it.

Comment: Back, in the newsgroups age, you would be called "topic's necromancer" :-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

with

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        //Do stuff
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhere in your `Activity`. The line could be in the `onCreate` method, and you override the `onOptionsItemSelected` in the `Activity's` body.

Comment: Doesn't register clicks with appcompat, and shows the back navigation button

Comment: Not a solution when using appcompat actionbar

Answer (score 1):

You can read more about the home button here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home

It explains how to clear previous the stack of previous activities and has some more links to best practices on navigation using the home button.