# How to make click on ActionBar Logo in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity, android-actionmode

I tried to do something on Click on icon in `ActionBar` but do nothing.I also like to do open **drawer_layout** on click on a icon in action bar. How to make it clickable and handle the event of it`s pressing?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ViewPager viewPager,viewPager01;
CustomSwipAdapter swip_adapter;
CustomSwipAdapter01 swip_adapter01;

String[] menu;
DrawerLayout dLayout;
ListView dList;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try{
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.sample_01);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    swip_adapter =new CustomSwipAdapter(this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(swip_adapter);

/*    viewPager01 = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager01);
    swip_adapter01 =new CustomSwipAdapter01(this);
    viewPager01.setAdapter(swip_adapter01);*/

    menu = new String[]{"Home","E-Gift Voucher"};
    dLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    dList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu);

    dList.setAdapter(adapter);
    dList.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);

    dList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            dLayout.closeDrawers();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("Menu", menu[position]);
            Fragment detail = new DetailFragment();
            detail.setArguments(args);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, detail).commit();
        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
 /*   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuInflater inf = getMenuInflater();
    inf.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_action,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);*/

    MenuInflater inf = getMenuInflater();
    inf.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_action,menu);
    return true;//super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
   // int id = item.getItemId();

     switch (item.getItemId()){
         case android.R.id.home:
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Click on Logo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return  true;
         default:
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: action bar is deprecated, please use toolbar

Comment: will you provide some example of toolbar

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Comment: http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android how to make clickable logo icon in actionbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030204/android-how-to-make-clickable-logo-icon-in-actionbar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_main_search_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent_semi"
    tools:context="com.worldofmoms.views.fragments.search_and_explore.SearchFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar_search"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
          android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
          app:theme="@style/ActionBar_Light"/>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_search"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Add in your activity `onCreate()`

```
       mToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_search);
       setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

> and Add

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
      if(id==android.R.id.home){
        // home button from toolbar clicked
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your activity onCreate(): i am quite sure it may help you...

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Custom code for image icon which redirects to homepage
    ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions()
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(actionBar.getThemedContext());
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            webViewPlaceholder.loadUrl("http://www.salebhai.com");
        } });
    ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.LEFT
            | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    layoutParams.leftMargin = 20;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    actionBar.setCustomView(imageView);


    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Thank you ,

happy Coding.....

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise, be sure you tailor your answer to *this* question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.